USB ports stops working after a while on Linux
I have Jetson Orin NX with kernel version 5.10.104-tegra
I have plugged in GPS device in the usb. Everything it works as expected but after a while just its stops. All usb devices are not accessible anymore. The Jetson doesn't recognise any device plugged in to the USB ports
When any device is not accessible anymore and I execute lsusb I see only that
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

After that if I execute dmesg I see that:
34.445027] r8169 0008:01:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[  34.445072] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  55.588490] r8169 0008:01:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[  58.573824] r8169 0008:01:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  80.129697] r8169 0008:01:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[  81.750695] r8169 0008:01:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[  88.825048] tegra-xusb 3610000.xhci: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[  88.833299] tegra-xusb 3610000.xhci: USBSTS:
[  88.837697] tegra-xusb 3610000.xhci: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[  88.845780] tegra-xusb 3610000.xhci: HC died; cleaning up
[  88.851370] tegra-xusb 3610000.xhci: hcd_reinit is disabled or in progress
[  88.851394] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  88.851397] usb 1-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  88.851549] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  88.852483] usb 1-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 4

I tried to unplug/plug devices but it does not help.
I updated all packages as well
I also tried few other things like:

disable power saving mode
in  /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf I added usbcore.autosuspend=-1 iommu=soft pci=nomsi intel_iommu=off

but also non of them helped. I really did huge research in google but with no result.
I really appreciate if you can help

Some faulty USB peripherals bringing down the whole USB hub happens, albeit rarely.

In my case it happens at least one per day and I have no idea how to prevent that
